# fetch image from excel using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with **Apache POI**.  I am able to read data from excel, but unable to read image from the excel.  How to read image from excel.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images

Comment: I read that image guide and also tried executing it.  **I got these errors -->**   List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();//Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<HSSFPictureData> to List

Comment: for (Iterator it = lst.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )//The method iterator() is undefined for the type List

Comment: PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();//Cannot cast from void to PictureData

Comment: String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();//The method suggestFileExtension() is undefined for the type PictureData

Comment: [Workbook.getAllPictures](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getAllPictures()) gets a [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). So `List` must be a `java.util.List` and `Iterator` must be a `java.util.Iterator`.

Comment: This error still persists-->PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();//Cannot cast from void to PictureData

Answer (score 2):

Instead of puzzling around let's have a complete example.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PictureData;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;

class ReadExcelImages {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("test.xls");
  //InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("test.xlsx");

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

  List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();
  int i = 1;
  for (Iterator it = lst.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
   PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();
   String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();
   byte[] data = pict.getData();
   if (ext.equals("png")){
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict" + i++ + ".png");
    out.write(data);
    out.close();
   } else if (ext.equals("jpeg")) {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict" + i++ + ".jpeg");
    out.write(data);
    out.close();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Works for me with `HSSF` (`*.xls`) as well as with `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`).